# How to nest JSON fields using grok filter in logstash?

Tags: json, logstash, logstash-grok

I receive logs from my Spring Boot App via **logback** and want to transform several fields to a nested separate json element in using **logstash filters**. I've done that with the 
`mutate` filter:

```
filter {
  mutate {
    rename => {
      "appName" => "[app][name]"
      "appNode" => "[app][node]"
      "appStatus" => "[app][status]"
      ... etc
    }
  }
}
```

and it works (I look at the result in Kibana). 
But it's not convienent to list all those fields (which I'm gonna have more than 3). It'd be great to write a regexp (perhaps) which would match fields starting with 'app' and nest them under 'app' element.

I know it's possible to achieve this with `ruby` and `grok` filters. I don't have enought time to learn ruby to write a script, so I want to know how can I group it using grok template?